# Using #define, good practice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

In the interest of cleaning up my code, is it good practice to use `#define` for more than a few lines of code?  Most examples are a few lines, defining dimensions etc.
In my example I have separate header file for the following piece of code.  Is it good practice to use `#define` this way?

```
#define KCHECKREFERENCE if([self.partClasses containsObject:@"Part1"]||[self.partClasses containsObject:@"Part2"]||[self.partClasses containsObject:@"Part3"]||[self.partClasses containsObject:@"Part4"]||[self.partClasses containsObject:@"Part5"]||[self.partClasses containsObject:@"Part6"]||[self.partClasses containsObject:@"ICDomesticEICPart7"]||[self.partClasses containsObject:@"ICDomesticEICPart8"] ){\
[self.currentPartView save];\
self.previousPartView = self.currentPartView;\
int nextPartNumber = 1;\
ICCertificateComponent *part = [self loadPart:nextPartNumber];\
self.currentPartView = part;\
CGRect nextPartViewFrame = self.currentPartView.view.frame;\
nextPartViewFrame.origin.x = 320.0f;\
self.currentPartView.view.frame = nextPartViewFrame;\
CGRect previousPartViewFrame = self.previousPartView.view.frame;\
previousPartViewFrame.origin.x = -320.0f;\
nextPartViewFrame.origin.x = 0;\
[self.view insertSubview:self.currentPartView.view belowSubview:self.navBarView];\
NSTimeInterval duration = 0.1;\
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration\
                 animations:^{\
                     self.previousPartView.view.frame = previousPartViewFrame;\
                     self.currentPartView.view.frame = nextPartViewFrame;\
                 }\
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {\
                     self.currentPartNumber = 1;\
                     self.navBarView.prevButton.enabled = NO;\
                    self.navBarView.nextButton.enabled = YES;\
                     [self.previousPartView.view removeFromSuperview];\
                     self.previousPartView = nil;\
                     if (self.currentPartView.showsShareOptions == YES) {\
                         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(shareButtonPressed:)];\
                     }\
                 }\
 ];\
```

Comment: The best place to ask for help in cleaning up code would be over at CodeReview.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  And especially not for something so specific.

Rather than `#define`, put this code in a method.

Comment: If this code was smaller and you needed it to be inline to run fast you may not want to put it in a method. Given the size the overhead of calling a method is quite small.

Comment: That may be true, but it's certainly not the case here.  Moreover, this is a code-cleanness question and not an optimization question.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert as @nhgrif1 wrote, it's not the case. Also don't try to be so smart, LLVM can be much smarter when it optimizes your stuff. Also readability is awful, debugging as well, ... It's a mess ... And if you need inlining, why not to use `inline` C function, which can be called from your ObjC method.

Comment: This tells you everything you want to know: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function

Comment: @Robert-Vojta look when I started programming you had to be smart!

Answer (score 2):

I know couple cases where define is good practice. For example `_countof` macro

```
#if !defined(_countof)
#if !defined(__cplusplus)
#define _countof(_Array) (sizeof(_Array) / sizeof(0[_Array]))
#else
template <typename _CountofType, size_t _SizeOfArray>
char (*__countof_helper(_CountofType (&_Array)[_SizeOfArray]))[_SizeOfArray];
#define _countof(_Array) sizeof(*__countof_helper(_Array))
#endif
#endif
```

But yours KCHECKREFERENCE is evil. You should use `inline` funcions instead. Why? At least because you can't set breakpoint inside yours macro.